# Not able to render a Polymer app using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, polymer

I am trying to generate an apk for a polymer app using cordova. But i am facing difficulty as the generated apk is not able to render properly in the mobile application (Android version 6.0 which is > 4.1 which is supported by Polymer). I referred [this](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/use-polymer-apache-cordova/) for building the app but it did not work. The polymer app is woking as expected in the web browser but when in apk form in a mobile it does not work.

[image: App Working in Web Browser]

[image: App not working in mobile Nexus 5 v 6.0]

Contents of Index.html

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>myApp</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="/src/main-app/main-app.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/gold-phone-input/gold-phone-input.html">


</head>

<body class="app">
    <paper-header-panel class="flex">
        <paper-toolbar class="medium-tall">
            <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
            <!-- flex class forces span to fill space between icons -->
            <span class="flex">Title</span>
            <!-- icon displays at right because of span class above -->
            <paper-icon-button id="morebutton" icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-tabs class="bottom fit" selected="0">
                <paper-tab>ONE</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>TWO</paper-tab>
            </paper-tabs>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <div>Content</div>
    </paper-header-panel>

    <gold-phone-input country-code="91" phone-number-pattern="XX-XX-XXXXXX">
    </gold-phone-input>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have also tried adding [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html) to Cordova but it still does not work.

Please let me know if any more information is required.

Will Appreciate any help.